# Hide variables until needed?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, parameters, var

I have a simple calculator for finding the dimensions of a couple shapes. It's supposed to be set up so the first function has a set of `if` statements that trigger one and only one of the other functions based on user input. But instead it's triggering all of them no matter what my answer is. This is because all the variable prompts are out in the open and it's just running through them all. How do I make it so it only runs the ones that correspond with the function being ran? It's also making it so all my console.log results are coming up NaN. How can I fix this?

//Main Function

```
        function theConjurer() {
            firstQuestion = prompt("Hi! This is my shape dimension calculator! I have three different shapes in this version but I can always add more! For now I have these three:\nCircle Area\nSphere Volume\nRectangular Prism Volume\n\nEnjoy!!!");
                return firstQuestion.toLowerCase(); //The answer to this prompt is supposed to spring one of the functions below.

            if(firstQuestion === "Circle" || firstQuestion === "Circle Area") { //If the answer is one of these strings, then it triggers the circle area function.
                console.log("You've slected Circle!")
                calcCircleArea();
            }

            else if(firstQuestion === "Sphere" || firstQuestion === "Sphere Volume") { //This one triggers the sphere volume function.
                console.log("You've slected Sphere!")
                calcSphereVolume();
            }

            else if(firstQuestion === "Prism" || firstQuestion === "Rectangular Prism" || firstQuestion === "Prism Volume" || firstQuestion === "Rectangular Prism Volume") { //This one is for volume of a rectangular prism.
                console.log("You've slected Rectangular Prism!")
                calcPrismVolume();
            }

            else {  //Anything else just brings up another prompt for the same answers.
                firstQuestion = prompt("Sorry, that's not one of the options I have right now. Try again!");
            }
        }

        theConjurer(); //To automatically bring up the starting function.


        //Function for Dimensions of a Circle

        var pi = 3.14; //pi rounded down to the hudredths place.
        var circleRadius = prompt("What is the radius of your circle?")

        calcCircleArea(pi, circleRadius); //Variable declarations.

        function calcCircleArea(p, r) { //
            var circleArea = p * Math.pow(r, 2);
            console.log("The circle you've entered is " + circleArea + " square units!");
        }


        //Function for Volume of a Sphere

        var fourThirds = (4/3);
        var radius = prompt("Do you know the diameter of your sphere? Just half that is your radius! What's the radius?"); //User input for the shape's radius.

        calcSphereVolume(fourThirds, pi, radius);

        function calcSphereVolume(f, p, r) {
            var sphereVolume = f * p * Math.pow(r, 3);
            console.log("Your sphere is " + sphereVolume + " cubed units! Congradulations!");
        }


        //Function for Dimensions of a Rectangular Prism

        var length = prompt("What's the length of this prism?"); //User input for the shape's length.
        var width = prompt("What's the width?"); //User input for the shape's width.
        var height = prompt("What is the height?"); //User input for the shape's height.

        calcPrismVolume(length, width, height); //Storage for the above three variables.

        function calcPrismVolume(l, w, h) { //Function and its parameters.
            var prismVolume = l * w * h; //New variable made from multiplying those parameters.
            console.log("Your prism is " + prismVolume + " cubed units!"); //Output of shape's area.
        }
```

Comment: The `||` OR operator is for a list of conditions and not for a list of values ... so it's `variable operator value1 || variable operator value2` and not `variable operator value1 || value2`. Try `if(firstQuestion === "Prism" || firstQuestion === "Rectangular Prism")` etc

Comment: Should be noted that you can do `["Sphere", "Sphere volume"].indexOf(firstQuestion) !== -1`, but you can't add multiple values with OR, it only separates statements

Comment: I may have to try the [ ] option. I made the changes you suggested with the OR operators and now any answer I input triggers the else statement.

Comment: Just use your debugger and stop asking basic questions like this. Sorry, that's my opinion. You will find a dozen of examples on Google if you look for "javascrpt prompt", "javascript NaN", "javascript type cast" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax doesn't do what you think. For example, this line is wrong:

```
if(firstQuestion === "Circle" || "Circle Area") { //If the answer is one of these strings, then it triggers the circle area function.
```

This doesn't check whether `firstQuestion` is either of those strings. It checkers whether one of two conditions is true or "truthy": (1) that `firstQuestion === "Circle"` or (2) `"Circle Area"`. That is, it treats `"Circle Area"` as a boolean expression, not as part of the comparison using `===`.

`"Circle Area"` is always truthy (in other words, treated as a boolean value, it evaluates as `true`). So, your `if` condition will always be satisfied. The same thing happens in each of the other `if` statements.

For each of your conditions, you need two comparisons, like this:

```
if(firstQuestion === "Circle" || firstQuestion === "Circle Area") {
```

You also need to add a few more `else`s or `return` early, so your main function needs to look like this:

```
//Main Function

    function theConjurer() {
        firstQuestion = prompt("Hi! This is my shape dimension calculator! I have three different shapes in this version but I can always add more! For now I have these three:\nCircle Area\nSphere Volume\nRectangular Prism Volume\n\nEnjoy!!!"); //The answer to this prompt is supposed to spring one of the functions below.

        if(firstQuestion === "Circle" || firstQuestion === "Circle Area") { //If the answer is one of these strings, then it triggers the circle area function.
            calcCircleArea();
        }

        else if(firstQuestion === "Sphere" || firstQuestion === "Sphere Volume") { //This one triggers the sphere volume function.
            calcSphereVolume();
        }

        else if(firstQuestion === "Prism" || firstQuestion === "Rectangular Prism" || firstQuestion === "Prism Volume" || firstQuestion === "Rectangular Prism Volume") { //This one is for volume of a rectangular prism.
            calcPrismVolume();
        }

        else {  //Anything else just brings up another prompt for the same answers.
            firstQuestion = prompt("Sorry, that's not one of the options I have right now. Try again!");
        }
    }
```

An even better solution would be to use a `switch`/`case`/`default` block, but that's not strictly necessary.

Comment: I tried that change and now it doesn't accept anything I input and just defaults to the else statement.

Comment: @MattLee that's because you are doing a simple `if` for each possibility, but not `else if`, and you don't do early returns. So, unless your very last `if` is satisfied, the associated `else` block will always execute, even if one of the other `if` statements was satisfied.

Comment: I have the if else statements in there now. It's still just jumping to the Sphere function no matter what I enter, even if I enter "Circle". Then it continues on to the Prism function.

Comment: @MattLee sorry, try the revised version. Had some copy-paste problems a minute ago.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't use switch/case/default. This is an assignment for class and we haven't covered that. I just wanted to know what I'm doing wrong with the code I've got because as it stands that's all I'm able to use on this assignment. if and else and if else statements, functions and loops.

Comment: @MattLee that's fine; you don't need it. If my answer helped, please remember to accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

`if(firstQuestion === "Circle" || "Circle Area")` always evaluates to `true` as `"Circle Area"` is a truthy statement. 
Try to change it to something like `if(firstQuestion === "Circle" || firstQuestion === "Circle Area")`.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, you should use Switch statement for this kind of choices. What's more you have a lot of bugs in your code. For example you used var p, but you in your function you used pi variable, which is undefined. I've fixed it for you. If this answer was helpful, please let me know by vote up.

**I've made working example for you JSFIDDLE --> http://jsfiddle.net/zpo4b3mo/**

```
//Lee_Matthew_Functions_Assignment_5/26/2015

//Main Function
    var pi = 3.14; //pi rounded down to the hudredths place.

function theConjurer() {
    var firstQuestion = prompt("Hi! This is my shape dimension calculator! I have three different shapes in this version but I can always add more! For now I have these three:\nCircle Area\nSphere Volume\nRectangular Prism Volume\n\nEnjoy!!!"); 

    switch(firstQuestion) {
        case "Circle" || "Circle Area":
            console.log('Selected Circle');
            calcCircleArea();
            break;
        case "Sphere" || "Sphere Volume":
            console.log('Selected Sphere');
            calcSphereVolume();
            break;
        case "Prism" || "Rectangular Prism" || "Prism Volume" || "Rectangular Prism Volume":
            console.log('Selected Prism');
            calcPrismVolume();
            break;
        default:  //Anything else just brings up another prompt for the same answers.
            console.log('None match');
            //firstQuestion = prompt("Sorry, that's not one of the options I have right now. Try again!");
            break;
    }

}

theConjurer(); //To automatically bring up the starting function.


//Function for Dimensions of a Circle

function calcCircleArea() {
    var radius = prompt('What is the radius?');
    var circleArea = pi * Math.pow(parseInt(radius), 2);
    console.log("The circle you've entered is " + circleArea + " square units!");
}


//Function for Volume of a Sphere

function calcSphereVolume() {
    var f = (4/3);
    var r = prompt("Do you know the diameter of your sphere? Just half that is your radius! What's the radius?"); //User input for the shape's radius.
    var sphereVolume = f * pi * Math.pow(r, 3);
    console.log("Your sphere is " + sphereVolume + " cubed units! Congradulations!");
}


    //Function for Dimensions of a Rectangular Prism


function calcPrismVolume() {

    var l = prompt("What's the length of this prism?"); //User input for the shape's length.
    var w = prompt("What's the width?"); //User input for the shape's width.
    var h = prompt("What is the height?"); //User input for the shape's height.//Function and its parameters.
    var prismVolume = l * w * h; //New variable made from multiplying those parameters.
    console.log("Your prism is " + prismVolume + " cubed units!"); //Output of shape's area.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are certain concepts I shouldn't use in this because it's an assignment for class and we haven't gone over them. One is switch/case/default. Also my three bottom functions have their variables set like that because we HAVE TO use parameters in them. I got the problem with the Circle function fixed on my own. There was just a variable missing. I still can't figure out how to stop it from calling up all three of the functions instead of just one and stopping.

Comment: Could you please share latest version via jsfiddle? I can check it for you